# Data structure issue in B tree

Tags: data-structures, tree, b-tree

As you know 2-3 tree is a private case of B tree, and my question was where B=3.
So each object in the tree can have between 3-6 objects except the root that can have 2 also...
reminder: when you take out objects in a 2-3 and B trees you can borrow from your brothers.

question: This is the tree:

[image]

Currently the height is 3, the question what is the minimum amount of leafs you need to take out for the height to be 2...?

my answer way 13 and another person is 12, who is right?

Comment: for me, after i took 12 i got to a tree that have C and D with 3 leafs for each and then i needed to take 1 more to loose one of the objects so i ended up with one root and 5 leafs

Comment: In a 2-3 tree, each internal node has either 1 value and 2 children, or 2 values and 3 children... not 3-6 children